# NopCommerce Minor version upgrade

Tags: nopcommerce

I am new-ish to NopCommerce having only installed it a month ago.  There are now some videos released related to my current version, but are not available / visible.  The upgrade refers to upgrading major versions only 3.10 to 3.20 and then to 3.30 (as an example), but not if you appear to have the same version (in this case 3.80).   A brief overview of the upgrade scripts does suggest that it will respect "if column exists", etc. but the XML resources are a bit more difficult to confirm.

Does anyone have experience with upgrading "between" versions?  The normal process of backing up and saving settings files will still be done - just wanted to know if others regularly do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I understand from your question is that you downloaded a version which is currently under development and want to upgrade your existing installation.

XML resources would not be a problem while upgrading. Because if resource name is matched with any existing resource, it will be updated and empty value would be deleted from DB.

Comment: Hi @Ratul, the version appears to be the same as I have (version number only), but there are definitely changes between the version I have and the "marketing video podcast - released this week".  It is probably suble minor release GIT updates.  Short answer - Probably.  Have you done such upgrades / updates on Nop?

Comment: If you downloaded the ongoing work from github, then please visit [Upgrade scripts](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/upgradescripts/3.80-the%20next%20version/upgrade.sql). This includes all the DB upgrades after 3.8 release.